# Web3js - Decode multisend ABI contract results in BigNumber Error

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation

I am trying to decode the following  [smart contract ABI](https://etherscan.io/address/0xb59fdff77a6175dfa4fe7af4281a52f61611eaa2#code). When I try to decode a transaction input with it, it yields following error:

```
Unhandled rejection BigNumber Error: new BigNumber() not a number: 27699642598250537994,27699642598250537994,27699642598250537994,27699642598250537994,27699642598250537994,27699642598250537994,27699642598250537994,...
```

I am using the following code to decode the contract:

```
    const source = fs.readFileSync("MultiSend.sol", "utf8");
    const compiledContract = solc.compile(source, 1);
    const abi = JSON.parse(compiledContract.contracts[":Airdropper"].interface);

    const abiDecoder = require("abi-decoder");
    abiDecoder.addABI(abi);

    Config.web3.eth.getTransaction("0x8f2c00ebd1f5bce60fcc09024423037813e7bc21f5e995f10bff225502b8beab").then((t: any) => {
        const decodedInput = abiDecoder.decodeMethod(t.input);

        // handle decoded input....
    });
```

My goal is to decode the multi-send operation of the contract.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue by using [another ABI decoder](https://github.com/miguelmota/ethereum-input-data-decoder)